# How to use require in Discordia(luvit)

Tags: lua, discord, require, luajit, luvit

So when i just use require(filename) it doesn't work, i mean if i use require("filename"), it thinks it's a module so can't open it, it only works if i use require("./filename.lua"), but then it doesn't get me any data from file i require. i can futher provide more details about file containing and other stuff, but that is what i need.
my main file:

```lua
local dia = require("discordia")
local tools = require("discordia-slash").util.tools()
local CLIENT = dia.Client():useApplicationCommands()
local mycommands = require('./cstmcommands.lua')
```

i have in CLIENT:on() print(Commands) which is the array that has function in it in cstmcommands.lua, but it prints nil. I tried printing other things from cstmcommands.lua, but it prints nil always.

Provide some informations, guides, tutorials, or answer the question straight how to solve this problem with require when even when i do require() it doesn't get data from file in Discordia core which is written on luvit.

terminal output

```
C:\Unnesessary\Smallbot on Lua>luvit ./main
2023-09-03 21:35:01 | [INFO]    | Discordia 2.11.2
2023-09-03 21:35:01 | [INFO]    | Connecting to Discord...
2023-09-03 21:35:02 | [INFO]    | Authenticated as (botname)
2023-09-03 21:35:02 | [INFO]    | Launching shard 0 (1 out of 1)...
2023-09-03 21:35:02 | [INFO]    | Shard 0 : Connected to wss://gateway.discord.gg
2023-09-03 21:35:02 | [INFO]    | Shard 0 : Received HELLO
2023-09-03 21:35:02 | [INFO]    | Shard 0 : Received READY
Uncaught Error: C:\Unnesessary\Smallbot on Lua\main.lua:26: attempt to index global 'Commands' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        C:\Unnesessary\Smallbot on Lua\main.lua: in function <C:\Unnesessary\Smallbot on Lua\main.lua:7>
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'error'
        C:/Unnesessary/Smallbot on Lua/deps/coro-channel.lua:16: in function 'assertResume'
        C:/Unnesessary/Smallbot on Lua/deps/coro-channel.lua:69: in function 'onPlain'
        ...nesessary/Smallbot on Lua/deps/secure-socket/biowrap.lua:76: in function <...nesessary/Smallbot on Lua/deps/secure-socket/biowrap.lua:61>
        [C]: in function 'run'
        [string "bundle:/init.lua"]:55: in function <[string "bundle:/init.lua"]:47>
        [C]: in function 'xpcall'
        [string "bundle:/init.lua"]:47: in function 'fn'
        [string "bundle:deps/require.lua"]:310: in function <[string "bundle:deps/require.lua"]:266>

C:\Unnesessary\Smallbot on Lua>pause
```

cstmcommands content

```
Commands = {}
Cmd = {
    ["вітання"] = {
        name = "вітання",
        description = "Надішли вітання боту, або обраному користувачу",
        options = {
            {
                name = "користувач",
                description = "Обери користувача, якому бот надішле повідомлення",
                type = "user",
                required = false,
                choises = nil
            }
        }
    }
}

function Commands:apply()
    entered_commands = {}
    for group, optcmd in pairs(Cmd) do
        for _, v in pairs(optcmd) do
            local SlashCommand = {}
            local option = {}
            
            for i, v in pairs(optcmd.options) do
                n = i
                local optiontype = v.type
                option = {tools.optiontype(optcmd.options.v.name, optcmd.options.v.description)}
            end
            SlashCommand = tools.slashCommand(optcmd.name, optcmd.description)
            local n = 0
           
            for i = 1, n, 1 do
                SlashCommand = SlashCommand:addOption(option[i])
            end
            entered_commands[group] = SlashCommand
        end
    end
    return entered_commands
end
```

Comment: What is the value of `package.path`, and what are the contents of `cstmcommands.lua`? Please try to construct a more complete [mre], as it is not particularly clear what the *exact* issue is.

Comment: @Oka i edited, look at cstmcommands content and i don't know what package. Path is

Comment: @Oka i used variable and printed it, package. path is 
.\?.lua;C:\Unnesessary\Smallbot on Lua\lua\?.lua;C:\Unnesessary\Smallbot on Lua\lua\?\init.lua;

Answer (score 0):

i found answer, here how to use require() in Discordia
if you have a command, use path to it from file you are requiring in `local Commands = require("./name of your file.lua")`
if you have many of commands require them too

```
Commands = require("./path/to/file.lua")
something = require('./idk.lua")
```

and then go to your file, and use return function like that

```
Commands = {1, 5, 10}
return Commands
```

remember to do it in your file, then you can print things from Commands
if you need to return many values, use

```
return {Commands, Something, else}
```

now you know how to require and can make some projects with it, but remember, file can't translate things to each other if only in one used require, so if you have values in 1st file and require it in 2nd, but you have values of 2nd in 1st, you have to identify them or require 2nd in 1st, like that:
1st file:

```
krona = require("./2ndfile.lua")
function doprint()
print(krona)
end
return doprint()
```

2nd:

```
local doprint = require("./1stfile.lua")
krona = 3
return krona
```